# How can I post comments on mongoose model with specific id

Tags: mongoose, ejs

I have created two mongoose models:

```
var Post = new Schema({
name: String,
description: String,
address: String,
comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
phoneNum: { type: Number,
    unique: true }   

  });
   module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", Post);

      var Comment = new Schema({
     comments: { type: String }
    });
     module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", Comment);
```

I am trying to figure out how to post a comment for a specific Post document by Id and how to render the comments for this document in my ejs view. I would really appreciate any help!